# Formula (how to calculate) Y axis cross-point of two intersecting lines

Tags: geometry

i.e. I have two lines:

[image]

A) Orange (`Y` axis starts at: `6`,  end at: `-3`)

B) Green  (`Y` axis starts at: `5`,  end at: `-2`)

the start/end `X` axis values are same. Please note, I don't have SLOPE(angle) information, we only know what I've mentioned.

How to calculate (what formula to use) to get the cross-point Y value?  it's about 0.8 estimately (as I see visually), but what is the formula I cant reach...  I've tried so far:

```
mid_orange = (orange_start_Y + orange_end_Y )/2
mid_green  = (green_start_Y  + green_end_Y  )/2
cross_point_Y= (mid_orange *m + mid_green *n )/2
```

I think I need correct `m` and `n` coefficients... I don't know...

Comment: I've found this: https://www.mathopenref.com/coordintersection.html  but cant find out though how to do that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-method: The equations of the lines are:
$$\begin{cases}y_{green}=-\frac93x+\frac{27}{3}\\ y_{orange}=-\frac73x+\frac{22}{3}\end{cases} \Rightarrow (x_0,y_0)=(5/2,3/2).$$
2-method: Use similarity of triangles:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]
$$\triangle BEO \sim \triangle BFC \Rightarrow \frac{BE}{BF}=\frac{EO}{FC} \Rightarrow \frac{BE}7=\frac{EO}3 \\
\triangle AEO \sim \triangle AGD \Rightarrow \frac{AE}{AF}=\frac{EO}{GD} \Rightarrow \frac{AE}9=\frac{EO}3 \\
\begin{cases}7AE=9BE \\ AE=BE+1\end{cases} \Rightarrow BE=\frac72 \Rightarrow y_0=5-\frac72=\frac32.$$

Answer (score 0):

I've also successfully used this formula:

```
xCoef = (orangeStartY - greenStartY)/(greenEndY-greenStartY-orangeEndY+orangeStartY)
CrossPointY = xCoef * (greenEndY-greenStartY) + greenStartY
```